# how to read call logs after call finished and stored in logs?

Tags: android

I am  reading call logs after call finish, according this if call is connected then call duration is greater than 0. If duration is greater than 0, I schedule next call on that number after 2 days. If call duration is 0 then I schedule next call on that number after 1 day.

My problem is that when call is connected then it scheduled correctly, but when call is not connect then previous text is shows. Sometimes it is correct and sometimes is not correct.

I open this activity from receiver. Please provide better solution.

Following is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
     /**
      * this values only set when call maked from app then it w
      * ill set auto filled some of filled in follow up
      *
      */
    if(flag!=null && flag.equalsIgnoreCase("Followup")/*&& state!=true*/){
        if(SharedPrefs.getBoolean(this, SharedPrefs.PREFS_AUTH, SharedPrefs.
           KEY_SCHEDULE_NEXT_FOLLOWUP, false))
            {
             findViewById(R.id.rl_followUp).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
             findViewById(R.id.rl_followUp).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        getCallDetails();

        /*  
        String strDateFormat = "hh:mm a";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(strDateFormat);
        calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
        */
        if(callDuration > 0){
           tvDateText.setText(timeInMilies(2));
           etFUComments.setText("Call is done");
        } else {
           tvDateText.setText(timeInMilies(1));
           etFUComments.setText(getResources().
               getString(R.string.call_not_connected_detail));
        }
    }
    super.onResume();
}

private void getCallDetails() {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    String strOrder = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC";
    /* Query the CallLog Content Provider */
    managedCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,
            null, null, strOrder);
    int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
    int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
    sb.append("Call Log :");
    if  (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
        phNum = managedCursor.getString(number);
        String callTypeCode = managedCursor.getString(type);
        String strcallDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
        callDate = new Date(Long.valueOf(strcallDate));
        callDuration =Integer.parseInt(managedCursor.getString(duration));
        String callType = null;
        int callcode = Integer.parseInt(callTypeCode);
        switch (callcode) {
            case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                callType = "Outgoing";
                break;
            case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                callType = "Incoming";
                break;
            case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                callType = "Missed";
                break;
        }
    }
    managedCursor.close();
}


public String timeInMilies(int day){
    Date date=new Date();//(86400000*2)
    long time= date.getTime();
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(time + (86400000 * day));
    //etFUComments.setText(String.valueOf(formatter.format(calendar.getTime())));
    return String.valueOf(formatter.format(calendar.getTime()));
}
```

Comment: thanks @mergenchik !!

Answer (score 0):

You can give some delay to open activity ,cause after call you suddenly open the activity and within that time there is not the current log.